# Image in ScrollViewer, fully visible & zoomable?

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a Win 8.1 app which displays an image which I want to allow the pinch/zooming on, to achieve this I put  control inside of a .

Depending on the size of the image (usually smaller ones whose resolution is less than the available size), things work fine, however for larger images, it insists on (visually) cutting off the bottom and requiring the manual scrolling down to see it.

The only way around this is to set VerticalScrollBarVisibility &                           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled... which comes with it's own issues. When set, I can pinch to zoom, but it quickly (and automatically) snaps the view back to the upper left corner.

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  MinZoomFactor=".25"
                  MaxZoomFactor="10" >
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Big Test Image.jpg" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Any suggestions as to what I need to tweak here or elsewhere to force the image to start fully displayed, and still be zoomable & focusable?

Comment: It appears that if I set either VerticalScrollBarVisibility or HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled, it is that direction which engages in the phantom snapping, but not the Auto/Enabled one.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following attributes to the ScrollViewer tag:

```
HorizontalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" ZoomSnapPointsType="None"
IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False" IsVerticalRailEnabled="False" ManipulationMode="All"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the same result is had with those additions, and when I remove or set VerticalScrollBarVisibility & HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to something else, while the phantom snapping goes away, the automatic clipping continues.

Comment: I'm not sure how it will behave, but could you try to wrap either the whole ScrollViewer or just the image in a ViewBox control?